# ./bin/cqlsh saying python not found

Tags: python, cassandra

I have installed cassandra 3.0.0 and trying to connect to connect cqlsh. when i try to hit ./bin/cqlsh from the  dir of installed cassandra I am getting

python not found. I am using ubunut14.04LTS

when i type python2 in my terminal it says

```
python2
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

when i type python3 in my terminal it says

```
 python3
Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

so this mean it is already installed . But yes when i type

python in terminal it says

```
python
The program 'python' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt-get install python-minimal
```

even when i install python-minimal it doesn work.

please suggest..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a symbolic link /usr/bin/python pointing to either /usr/bin/python2 or /usr/bin/python3